# Pagination jquery easyui

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, pagination

I'm trying to make a pagination for a datagrid. I can import ok the data from an oracle db, based an a query. All data are showed in browser. The problem is that all data are on one page. I must scroll down to see all data. When I press next button nothing happens, just refresh the page, and the data are the same. I can't go on next or previous page. 
Here is my code:

```
<html>  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="jquery,ui,easy,easyui,web">
    <meta name="description" content="easyui help you build your web page easily!">
    <title>jQuery EasyUI Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/gray/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var pager = $('#tt').datagrid('getPager');  // get the pager of datagrid
            pager.pagination({
                showPageList:false,
                buttons:[{
                    iconCls:'icon-search',
                    handler:function(){
                        alert('search');
                    }
                },{
                    iconCls:'icon-add',
                    handler:function(){
                        alert('add');
                    }
                },{
                    iconCls:'icon-edit',
                    handler:function(){
                        alert('edit');
                    }
                }],
                onBeforeRefresh:function(){
                    alert('before refresh');
                    return true;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>  
<body
```

> 

```
<?PHP
header('Refresh: 900');

require_once 'connect.php';

$page = isset($_POST['page']) ? intval($_POST['page']) : 1;
$rows = isset($_POST['rows']) ? intval($_POST['rows']) : 10;
$sort = isset($_POST['sort']) ? strval($_POST['sort']) : 'NGM_CREATION_TIME';
$order = isset($_POST['order']) ? strval($_POST['order']) : 'desc';
$offset = ($page-1)*$rows;

$sql = "select c.case_id as NGM_ID,   
       s.NE_PRIORITAET as NE_PRIO,
       case substr(s.NE_ID, 2,1)
         when '0' then 'Zentrale'
         when '1' then 'Nord'
         when '2' then 'Nord' 
         when '3' then 'Ost'
         when '4' then 'Ost'
         when '5' then 'Mitte'
         when '6' then 'West'
         when '7' then 'Süd'
         when '8' then 'Mitte'
         when '9' then 'Süd'
         else          'Error'
       end as REGION,         
       c.STATUS_NGM as NGM_STATUS,
       s.AUFTRAG as AUFTRAG,
       s.NE_ID as NE_ID,
       s.STATUS as SAP_STATUS,
       substr(to_timestamp(to_char(Sysdate, 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') - to_timestamp(to_char(s.CREATION_TIME, 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 8,12) as DIFF_BEGINN_SAP_ENDE,
      case trim(s.KATEGORIE)
         when '1' then 'INSLA'
         when '2' then 'OUTSLA'
         else          s.KATEGORIE
       end as SLA,
       to_char(c.CREATION_TIME, 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
        as NGM_CREATION_TIME,
       case s.NE_PRIORITAET
         when 'A' then substr(to_char((to_timestamp(to_char((Sysdate + 6/24), 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss') - to_timestamp(to_char(s.CREATION_TIME, 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')), 'dd hh24:mi:ss'),8,12)
         when 'B' then substr(to_char((to_timestamp(to_char((Sysdate + 1), 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss') - to_timestamp(to_char(s.CREATION_TIME, 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss')), 'dd hh24:mi:ss'), 8,12)
         when 'C' then substr(to_char((to_timestamp(to_char((Sysdate + 1), 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss') - to_timestamp(to_char(s.CREATION_TIME, 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss')), 'dd hh24:mi:ss'),8,12)
         else          substr(to_char((to_timestamp(to_char((Sysdate + 1), 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss') - to_timestamp(to_char(s.CREATION_TIME, 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss')), 'dd hh24:mi:ss'), 8,12)
        end as TIME_LEFT_OVERRUN,

       c.URSACHE_KURZ as URSACHE_KURZ,
       s.BEARBEITER as BEARBEITER
      from dash_omc_cases c, 
       dash_omc_sap s";


$stid = oci_parse($db_con, $sql);

oci_define_by_name($stid, 'NGM ID', $NGM_ID);
oci_define_by_name($stid, 'NE Prio', $NE_Prio); 
oci_define_by_name($stid, 'Region', $Region);
oci_define_by_name($stid, 'NGM Status', $NGM_Status); 
oci_define_by_name($stid, 'Auftrag', $Auftrag);
oci_define_by_name($stid, 'NE ID', $NE_ID);
oci_define_by_name($stid, 'SAP Status', $SAP_Status); 
oci_define_by_name($stid, 'Diff Beginn Sap Ende', $Diff_Beginn_Sap_Ende);
oci_define_by_name($stid, 'NGM Creation Time', $NGM_Creation_Time);
oci_define_by_name($stid, 'Time Left/Overrun', $Time_Left_Overrun);
oci_define_by_name($stid, 'Ursache Kurz', $Ursache_Kurz);
oci_define_by_name($stid, 'Bearbeiter', $Bearbeiter);


oci_execute($stid);
?>
```

## DataGrid

```
<table id="tt" title="Load Data" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:1300px;height:400px"
        url="connect.php"
        iconCls="icon-save" rownumbers="true" pagination="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th field="NGM_ID" width="80px">NGM ID</th>
            <th field="NE Prio" width="80px">NE Prio</th>
            <th field="Region" width="80px" align="right">Region</th>
            <th field="NGM Status" width="80px" align="right">NGM Status</th>
            <th field="Auftrag" width="80px">Auftrag</th>
            <th field="NE ID" width="80px" align="center">NE ID</th>
            <th field="SAP Status" width="80px" align="center">SAP Status</th>
            <th field="Diff Beginn Sap End" width="120px" align="center">Diff Beginn Sap End</th>
            <th field="SLA" width="120px" align="center">SLA</th>
            <th field="NGM Creation Time" width="120px" align="center">NGM Creation Time</th>
            <th field="Time Left Overrun" width="120px" align="center">Time Left/Overrun</th>
            <th field="Ursache Kurz" width="120px" align="center">Ursache Kurz</th>
            <th field="Bearbeiter" width="120px" align="center">Bearbeiter</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>


<?php 

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

?>
<tr>
    <td style="border: 7px solid; width: 80px; "> <?php echo $row['NGM_ID']; ?></td>
    <td style="border: 7px solid; width: 80px; "> <?php echo $row['NE_PRIO']; ?></td>
    <td style="border: 7px solid; width: 80px; "> <?php echo $row['REGION']; ?></td>
    <td style="border: 7px solid; width: 80px; "> <?php echo $row['NGM_STATUS']; ?></td>
    <td style="border: 7px solid; width: 80px; "> <?php echo $row['AUFTRAG']; ?></td>
    <td style="border: 7px solid; width: 80px; "> <?php echo $row['NE_ID']; ?></td>
    <td style="border: 7px solid; width: 80px; "> <?php echo $row['SAP_STATUS']; ?></td>
    <td style="border: 7px solid; width: 120px; "> <?php echo $row['DIFF_BEGINN_SAP_ENDE']; ?></td>
    <td style="border: 7px solid; width: 120px; "> <?php echo $row['SLA']; ?></td>
    <td style="border: 7px solid; width: 120px; "> <?php echo $row['NGM_CREATION_TIME']; ?></td>
    <td style="border: 7px solid; width: 120px; "> <?php echo $row['TIME_LEFT_OVERRUN'];  ?></td>
    <td style="border: 7px solid; width: 120px; "> <?php echo $row['URSACHE_KURZ']; ?></td>
    <td style="border: 7px solid; width: 120px; "> <?php echo $row['BEARBEITER']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

what I do :

I formated data, where I take care of pagination ans sorted column, in the second function of point 2.

1| get data with a count to know how many result you have :

```
public static function searchByDepAsArrayBis($dep)
{
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('*')
    ->from('Objectif')
    ->leftJoin('OSDep','Objectif.Id_OSDep = OSDep.Id_OSDep')
    ->where('OSDep.DivisionAbr like :dep', array(':dep'=>$dep.'%'));

    if($command)
    {
        $data = $command->queryAll();

        return array($data,count($data));
    }
}
```

2| put data in place : look for pagination.

```
public function actionDataDep($dep)
{
    $objectif = new Objectif;
    $this->amILog();
    // get data + countData
    //$lTemp=Parametre::searchByUserAsArray($idUser,$role);
    $lTemp=$objectif->searchByDepAsArrayBis($dep);


        // Define output to encode
        $lOutput = array(
                "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
                "iTotalRecords" => count($lTemp),
                "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $lTemp[1],
                "aaData" => $this->dataDesktopDep($lTemp[0])
        );


    //  encode and show result
    echo json_encode($lOutput);
}

private function dataDesktopDep($aResults)
{       
    $lData = array();
    // column definition
    $lColumns = array('Id_Objectif','Libelle', 'AbrProprio', 'LibProprio','Statut', 'Alerte', 'Sante');


        // loop each result
        foreach($aResults as $result)
        {

            $row = array();

            //  format data in right form
            foreach($lColumns as $column)
            {
                if( $column == 'Id_Objectif' )
                    $row[] = $result['Id_Objectif'];
                else if ( $column == 'Libelle' )
                {
                    $p = Objectif::model()->findByPk($result['Id_Objectif']);
                    $row[] = $p->Libelle;//$result['Libelle'];      
                }   
                else if( $column == 'Alerte' )
                {

                    $p = Objectif::model()->findByPk($result['Id_Objectif']);
                        if($p->Alerte == 'green')
                            $row[] = CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl."/images/icones/green.png","",array("style"=>"margin:auto;width:50px;height:25px;margin-top:2px;"));
                        else if($p->Alerte == 'red')
                            $row[] = CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl."/images/icones/red.png","",array("style"=>"margin:auto;width:50px;height:25px;margin-top:2px;"));
                        else if($p->Alerte == 'orange')
                            $row[] = CHtml::image(Yii::app()->baseUrl."/images/icones/orange.png","",array("style"=>"margin:auto;width:50px;height:25px;margin-top:2px;"));

                }
                else if($column == 'AbrProprio')
                {
                    $row[] = $result['ProprioAbr'];
                }
                else if($column == 'LibProprio')
                {
                    $row[] = $result['ProprioLib'];
                }
                else if( $column == 'Statut' )
                {
                    $p = Objectif::model()->findByPk($result['Id_Objectif']);

                    $row[] = $p->Statut;
                }
                else if( $column == 'Sante' )
                {                   
                    $p = Objectif::model()->findByPk($result['Id_Objectif']);

                    $row[] = $row[] = $p->MoyennePerso;
                }



            }

            $lData[] = $row;
        }


        if($aResults!=null)
        {


                // SORT
                if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
                {

                    /*if($_GET['iSortCol_0']==0)
                     $lCommand->order('i.CodeInt '.($_GET['sSortDir_0']==='asc' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC'));
                    else if($_GET['iSortCol_0']==1)
                        $lCommand->order('i.Libelle '.($_GET['sSortDir_0']==='asc' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC'));
                    else if($_GET['iSortCol_0']==2)
                        $lCommand->order('isp.SousCom1 '.($_GET['sSortDir_0']==='asc' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC'));*/

                    //if($_GET['iSortCol_0']==0)
                    //{
                    if($_GET['sSortDir_0']==='asc')
                    {
                        // Obtient une liste de colonnes
                        foreach ($lData as $key => $row) {
                            $rang[$key]  = $row[$_GET['iSortCol_0']];
                        }
                        array_multisort($rang, SORT_ASC, $lData);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach ($lData as $key => $row) {
                            $rang[$key]  = $row[$_GET['iSortCol_0']];
                        }
                        array_multisort($rang, SORT_DESC, $lData);
                    }
                    //}
                }



                //PAGINATION

                if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
                {
                    $tabPagin = array();

                    for($i = $_GET['iDisplayStart']; $i<($_GET['iDisplayLength']+$_GET['iDisplayStart'])&& $i<count($lData) ;$i++)
                    {
                    $tabPagin[] = $lData[$i];
                    }
                }

                // Set the formated result in the Tab 


                return $tabPagin;
            }
            else 
            {
                return $lData;
            }

}
```

3| And finally my view

```
<div>
<script>
var oTable;
var oSettings;

$(document).ready(function ()
{                        
  bTable=$('#tableDGO4').dataTable({


            "aoColumnDefs": [


                    {"bVisible":false, "aTargets":[0]}, 
                    {"sWidth":"30px", "aTargets":[2,3,4,5,6]},
                    {"sWidth":"300px", "aTargets":[1]},
                    {"bAutoWidth":true, "aTargets":[0,1,3,2,4,5,6]},
                    {"bSortable":true, "aTargets":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]}

                    ],
            "oLanguage": {
                  "oPaginate": {
                        "sNext": "<img class='middle' src= '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/page_next.png';?>' />",
                        "sPrevious": "<img class='middle' src= '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/page_previous.png';?>' />",
                        "sFirst": "<img class='middle' src= '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/page_first.png';?>' />",
                        "sLast": "<img class='middle' src= '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/page_last.png';?>' />"
                  },
                "sInfo": "Résultats _START_ à _END_ - _TOTAL_ objectifs",
                "sInfoFiltered": "",
                "sSearch": "Filtrer les résultats : ",
                "sEmptyTable": "Votre recherche n'a ramené aucun résultat.",
                "sInfoEmpty": "Votre recherche n'a ramené aucun résultat.",
                "sProcessing" : "Chargement...",
                "sLengthMenu" : "Montrer _MENU_ résultats par page"
                },
            "sDom": '<"H"li>tr<"F"p>',
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "<?php  echo $this->createUrl('site/dataDep', array('dep'=>'DGO4')); ?>",
            "aLengthMenu":[10,25,50,75,100],
            "iDisplayLength":10,

            "createdRow": function( row, data ) {
                if ( data[5] == 'red' ) {
                  $(row).addClass( 'red' );
                }
                else if ( data[5] == 'green' ) {
                  $(row).addClass( 'green' );
                }
                else if ( data[5] == 'orange' ) {
                      $(row).addClass( 'orange' );
                }
            },
            "fnDrawCallback":function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex){
                // Fonction appelée quand clic sur une ligne du corps du tableau
                $('#tableDGO4 tbody tr').click( function(id){ 
                     var col = bTable.fnGetData( this );
                     var idParam = col[0];
                     document.location.href = "<?php echo $this->createUrl('Objectif/view').'/id/'; ?>"+idParam;
                });




            }

        });
    } 
);

</script>

<table id="tableDGO4">
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Id Obj</th>
     <th>Libellé</th>
     <th>Abréviation propriétaire</th>
     <th>Libellé propriétaire</th>
     <th>Statut</th>
     <th>Alerte</th>          
     <th>Santé</th>         
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="CurseurMain" >
    </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

I hope his can help you to fix your problem.